# Confusing billing on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Compute Instance service, first time using it, and I noticed that the billing was a bit too much.

After doing some research, Google is an on-demand service, which means I pay for what I use, but that still doesn't make any sense. Trying to crunch the numbers, it makes sense that I also have to pay for the egress, but the numbers don't add up properly. It's been about six days since I opened the n1-standard-4, and that comes out as 97 dollars a month, but I've been charged 30 dollars since opening it up (egress not included).

So basically I'm being charged 10 days worth of their service when it's only been six days. And the network egress is also not innocent either.

I'm trying to figure out what all the numbers mean, and also what the "Estimated charges" on the dashboard means. Is there some kind of hidden stat behind everything that I just didn't read about?

edit: [full billing report](http://prntscr.com/npjuxk)

Comment: Hard to say without your billing report, but I'd wager something like disk/snapshot storage.

Comment: On what date did you open the instance? This bill seems to be for 8 days and 4 hours of usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not Google Cloud Billing Department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An n1-standard-4 instance in Montreal is $0.2092 per hour (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#machinetype)). Your usage is for 196 hours (eight days, four hours). That gives an expected usage charge of $41.

Ignoring the ingress/egress and your sustained usage discount, you have two billing items left, $27.32 for the 4 cores and $13.73 for the 15 GiB of RAM. $27.32 plus $13.73 is $41.05, which is right on target.